# PHPmyadmin - serverside shows a blank page on all browsers

Tags: php, windows, phpmyadmin, server

When I visit mydomain.com/phpmyadmin I get a blank page and I can't see the login page. It doesn't show any error and it loads and works on other PCs but this one!
I tried Firefox, Chrome and Opera - NONE worked on this PC

Localhost works fine

My Operating system is windows 7

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Putting phpmyadmin in a subfolder of your root domain named so obviously is not recommended, as it can lead to security flaws (malicious bots trying to access your website's database). Instead, put it in a folder with an unguessable and non-obvious name. (e.g. mydomain.com/joes-cat-is-really-cute/)

Comment: @Howl: Having the folder named not so obviously isn't a way to protect your data. The URL can be scanned.

Comment: Alright, I know that but this is not my system and I want to login to it to edit. Its a new unpublished system @D4V1D

Comment: The longer it is, though, the harder it becomes (for instance, with the above example, it should take at least 4194304 retries).

Comment: Its loading on other pcs.. example.co/phpmyadmin .. its works fine .. but on my PC it shows a blank page do you know why?

Comment: @Naz970: Check your log (or have your `error_reporting` enabled).